# Run Oracle query from Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I want to run the query: "DESCRIBE table_name;"

```
statement = this.connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rset = statement.executeQuery("DESCRIBE table_name");
```

and I got this error:

```
 " java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"
```

what is the problem?

Comment: `describe` is not a valid SQL statement, it's a `SQL*Plus` command. Valid SQL statements (that can be run through JDBC) are listed in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/toc.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DESC` is a `SQL*Plus` command. SO, you cannot use it via JDBC/ODBC.
An alternative can be like this below.

```
select RPAD(COLUMN_NAME,30)||' '||DATA_TYPE||'('||DATA_LENGTH||')' as descr
FROM all_tab_cols
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('YOUR_TABLE') and owner=UPPER('SCHEMA_NAME');
```

`all_tab_cols` is a *data dictionary table*(view) which contains the table metadata

[Oracle's Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm)

Answer (score 2):

`DESC[RIBE]` is a SQL*Plus command, not a SQL statement. The DESC command queries the Oracle data dictionary, something like:

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
  from USER_TAB_COLUMNS
 where TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
describe user2.flights;
```

Here user2 is database name and flights is table name. Try this.

Or use next query

```
select *
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
 order by column_id;
```

Use this query.

**column_id** is the "order" of the column in the table.

You should ensure that '**MY_TABLE**' is capitalised unless you've been adding tables with casing ( a bad idea ) in which case you need to use something like = **"MyTable"**

Comment: Where can I find the database name?
I work with Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: use another. It may be helpful to u.

Comment: In Oracle `user2` is the schema, which is the same as the user that owns the object - probably yourself, in which case you can omit it; and if you're looking in `user_*` tables you can only see your own objects anyway. It is not the database name. (And if the object was created with a quoted identifier, you still should not use double-quotes for the value: `= 'MyTable'`).